# How should I translate “power distance”?

Tags: translation

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_distance), “power distance” is the extent to which the lower ranking individuals of a society "accept and expect that power is distributed unequally".

- [Power](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/power): I could pick 力, 能力, 権力, 勢力, 支配力, 政権, 権限, 職権 or パワー.
- [Distance](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/distance): I could pick 距離, 道のり, 間隔, 遠方 or ディスタンス.

Which terms should I pick in translating “power distance”?

Comment: By the way, if you don't know how to accept an answer yet, please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Comment: @naruto: Oh, I missed that part! Thank you very much for bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like people who are good at sociology mainly use **権力格差**, which I feel is reasonable and intuitive. 距離 is too literal. "Power distance index" would be 権力格差指数.

- 古川裕康, [Hofstedeの多文化社会理論](http://ooishi-lab.com/2010/10/hofstede%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%9A%E6%96%87%E5%8C%96%E7%A4%BE%E4%BC%9A%E7%90%86%E8%AB%96.html)
- 白木三秀, [G・ホフステード＝G・J・ホフステード＝ミンコフ『多文化世界─違いを学び未来への道を探る』](http://www.jil.go.jp/institute/zassi/backnumber/2016/04/pdf/068-071.pdf) (PDF)

A somewhat casual but easy-to-understand definition would be something like "(下側から見た時の)上下関係の強さ/厳しさ/受容度".